# Fun with probability measure functions

Tags: probability-theory

We have a transition matrix $M =(p_{i,j})$, i and j being elements of the set S, and a probability measure function $f_0(i_0)$, on the set S. Define for all natural numbers n $f_n(i_0,...,i_n)= f_0(i_0)p_{i_{0}i_{1}}...p_{i_{n-1}i_{n}}$. Show that $f_n$ is a probability measure function on $S^{n+1}$.

I am quite lost here. I'm assuming I have to do a proof by induction to prove the properties of the probability measure function for all n, but I'm just not seeing how to prove that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: The sum $\sum_{i_0} f_0(i_0)$ is $1$, so for $n=0$ you have a probability function. So you just need to note that for a transition matrix, you have $\sum_j p_{ij} = 1$ for all $i$, and the proof will follow by induction.

More formally,

$$\sum_{i_0,\ldots,i_n} f_0(i_0)p_{i_0 i_1} \cdots p_{i_{n-1} i_n} = \sum_{i_0,\ldots,i_{n-1}} f_0(i_0)p_{i_0 i_1} \cdots p_{i_{n-2} i_{n-1}}\cdot (\sum_{i=1}^{|S|} p_{i_{n-1},i})$$

$$ = \sum_{i_0,\ldots,i_{n-1}} f_0(i_0)p_{i_0 i_1} \cdots p_{i_{n-2} i_{n-1}}\cdot 1 = 1$$

by the induction hypothesis.

Comment: I understand what you're saying here, but I don't see any sums. I might be misreading the question?

Comment: @Elswyyr The sums come in when you want to prove that you have a probability measure on $S^{n+1}$. In order to have a probability measure, all probability values must be non-negative and they must add up to be $1$. If you factorize your sum by grouping together all terms that have the last variable equal, then you will get that the coefficient is $1$ for each choice of last variable (by induction), and therefore the sum is equal to the sum over all choices of last variable, which is again $1$ by assumption. Non-negativity is trivial to establish.

Comment: I'm thinking this is a notation issue. I'm reading the $p_{i,j}$ as a single entry in the transition matrix, so our product of $p_{i,j}$ is the product of various entries in this arbitrary stochastic matrix, which seems wrong, but I can't figure out what else it's supposed to mean.

Comment: @Elswyyr No you're right, it's a product. Just note that a sum of products over all choices of $k$ terms is equal to the sum of products over all choices of $k-1$ terms, multiplied by the sum of terms (and the sum terms is $1$ because you have a probability transition matrix).

Comment: Is is possible for you to write this identity up formally? Because I'm not sure what you mean. I'm not the best at reading math in english, I'm afraid.

Comment: @Elswyyr I edited with the equation to make the induction hypothesis work showing that you always get a probability distribution where the probabilities add up to be $1$.